# How Would Post-Traumatic Stress be Expressed in (Contemporary) Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

While researching the possibility of the occurrence of post traumatic stress disorder (PTSD), in the Roman army, I found this article from *Historia* magazine: ["Did Roman Soldiers Suffer PTSD?" by Anthony Riches (2017)](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506124044/http://www.historiamag.com/roman-ptsd/).

The article discusses contrasting views: PTSD has been around since the inception of warfare; or else it is the standards and mores of the contemporary world that make brutality difficult to bear. The article includes some anecdotal evidence of PTSD affecting Roman soldiers but, of course, it's impossible to prove anything. Prior to the American Civil War, the condition had no name.

How would "post-traumatic stress disorder" be expressed in Latin?

EDIT 3/2/2022:

(The assumption is that the Roman World, like many societies, in many time-periods, had no name for this condition. Therefore, this question is not asking what Roman soldiers may have called the symptoms.)

There does not appear to be a Latin word for "stress" & "traumaticus" relates to the healing of wounds rather than the cause of them. It would have to be something like:

> "post onerem terroris" = "post burden of terror".

It's not a great fit though it's the constant fear, in a warzone, that contributes to the generation of the traumatic stress.

Any thoughts?

Comment: There is a brief discussion of whether ancient soldiers suffered PTSD here: https://acoup.blog/2020/04/24/fireside-friday-april-24-2020/. This review discusses the story of how PTSD became recognised as a condition, which you might find interesting: https://slatestarcodex.com/2019/11/12/book-review-the-body-keeps-the-score/

Comment: @dbmag9: Both. Some psychologists opine that PTSD is a "new" phenomenon (circa 19th. Century); difficult to believe. The one question begets the other. Did the Romans suffer PTSD; if so what might they have called it? It may be the case is that generations of victims probably did not wish to discuss it, let alone give it a name.