# What Might Roman Soldiers Have Called the Symptoms of Post-Traumatic Stress?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Following on from Q: [How Would Post-Traumatic Stress be Expressed in (Contemporary) Latin?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/17666/1982) and given the entirely fair assumption that PTSD has bedevilled warriors since the inception of warfare, what might Roman soldiers have called the symptoms?

A guess:

> "malis avibus belli." = "to be under the influence of the evil birds (spirits) of war."

Comment: You might be interested in this: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/12628/did-roman-troops-suffer-from-ptsd